# Homemade 12/3 sjoow extension cord

Tags: extension

I'm making an extension cord from 12/3 from sjoow wire. I have a 15amp gfci and a 15amp duplex outlet. Do I use 15amp or 20amp outlets, or would it matter?

Comment: If the outlet is 15A, that pretty much means the plug you put in needs to be 15A. 20s will go either way, 15s only take 15s.

Answer (score 3):

On the extension cord itself, the socket must = the plug.  So 15 and 15......   Or 20 and 20.

On the wall receptacle, on 15A circuits (circuits with #14 wire and 15A breakers) you must use 15A in-wall sockets.

If a circuit is all #12 in-wall wire, and the breaker is 20A, then you are free to choose either 15A or 20A in-wall receptacles.  Provided you are using dual sockets like the normal kind.

If a circuit powers one single "solo" socket, then the socket amps must match breaker amps.